# PHP logging in redirection

Tags: php, session, redirect

i'm working on a site and when I try to login, it automatically redirects me back to the login page not allowing me to login. I think its the sessions, but not sure. If someone could please take a look for me. Its a dashboard based site so its supposed to redirect the user to there correct dash`board by there rank, but it seems its not working. Heres the login page:

**Login:**

```
    <?php
require 'core/config.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $username = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);

    if(empty($username) or empty($password))
    {
        echo 'You must fill in both boxes!';
    } else {
        $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'");
        while($row = $query->fetch_array())
        {
            $dbpassword = $row['Password'];
        }

        if($password !== $dbpassword)
        {
            echo 'Password was incorrect.';
        } else {
            $query1 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."'");
            while($rows = $query1->fetch_array())
            {
                $rank = $rows['Rank'];
            }

            if($rank === 'admin')
            {
                $_SESSION['admin'] = '1';
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

                echo '<script>window.location="admin/index.php";</script>';
            }
            elseif ($rank === 'partner')
            {
                registerSession('partner', '1');
                registerSession('username', $username);

                header('Location: partner/');
            }
            elseif ($rank === 'trainee')
            {
                registerSession('trainee', '1');
                registerSession('trainee', '1');

                header('Location: trainee/');
            }
            else 
            {
                echo 'You aren\'t a member.';
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**Code to redirect if not logged in:**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['partner']))
{
$_SESSION['username'];

} else {
header("location: ../index.php")
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you have `session_start();` in `core/config.php`? If not, then you should add it either there or here.

Comment: You can't set a session without session_start(); Add it to the top of your code under require 'core/config.php'; and try again.

Comment: Sidenote: This -> `md5` is a `no-no`. Don't use that. [`> Use this <`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) and what is `registerSession` ? Are you using some type of framework, function and/or class?

Comment: What Fred said, if you are using PHP >= 5.3.7 use this https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the session variable `partner` is not being set. So

Instead of

```
registerSession('partner', '1');
registerSession('username', $username);
```

Make use of

```
$_SESSION['partner']=1;
$_SESSION['username']=$username;
```

Try to add `session_start(); ob_start();` on the top of your **`config.php`** file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're logging in as admin or a trainee, not as a partner in which case you don't have a session variable for "partner"

Change your redirect code to something like this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['partner'])||isset($_SESSION['admin']||isset($_SESSION['trainee'])))
```

Comment: Well in this case it doesn't matter, I have it as partner because I was testing to see if the partner side did the same thing, thats why I put the partner redirection

Comment: Ah, I see, then check Majid's comment on your question about including `session_start` on the config.php file

Comment: Do read the comments that have been placed underneath your question. @user3051246 - Not knowing what exactly `registerSession()` is, or is coming from, can lead to everyone shooting golf balls in the dark.